# Control logging locally

Tags: python, logging, local

I am building one function that calls a function from another package.  In one scenario, the function in the other package logs a warning each time it runs (1000 times).

I only want to display one of those warnings and I do not want to modify any global logging settings for the user.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Is this a command line program with the log messages being written to stdout/strerr?

Comment: Does the other package use the python logging library or does it roll its own (or just use print)?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  It uses pythons logging package.  I am building a tool that people may be using in either command line or in interactive mode.  I don't want the user to have to control logging.

Answer (score 0):

The file handle used for stdout can be changed before calling the function, causing the warnings to be written to a file.  You could then read just the first line from that file and print it.  Something like:

```
import sys
originalStdout = sys.stdout
outf = open('outputfile', 'r+')
sys.stdout = outf  # send stdout to outputfile
package.function()  # this will write output to outputfile
sys.stdout = originalStdout  # restore original stdout handle
outf.seek(0) # go to begining of outputfile
print outf.readline()  # print first line from outputfile
```

Not sure if that qualifies as "simple," but it may work.

Comment: In this case I am not writing stdout to a file.  I am developing a tool so the user could be in either interactive mode or command line and I am not saving any stdout to file.